# Thunderbolt ethernet adapter ist not appearing in netwoks tab

Tags: macos, thunderbolt, ethernet

I have bought an Apple Thunderbolt Ethernet Adapter and can't seem to get it to work.

It simply does not appear in the Network section of System preferences, even though the System Information dialog shows it is connected.

Here is how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kaFO.jpg

I have tried everything from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/229189/200645) already.

I have el capitan and a retina macbook pro.

EDIT: I took it to the store and they confirmed it works fine. So it seems to be a software issue.

EDIT2: I solved it by reinstalling from scratch.

Comment: What happens when you add "Thunderbolt 1" interface (not the bridge)?

Comment: Nothing. I also tried both thunderbolt ports already.

Comment: Strange- if it's still under warranty you might want to have it swapped out just to be sure. I know when NetBooting you have to have the adaptor connected before starting up but not sure that'll really help here.

Comment: When you tried creating the interface, did you have Console open and did you watch for any relevant entries? If you're comfortable with the command line, you might see if you can create the interface that way in verbose mode. I'd have to dig and test the actual commands.

Comment: There is nothing in the Console that might indicate something. No matter if I plug and unplug or try to add the interface. If it were not for the system information saying the adapter is connected I would be sure that it is a hardware issue. I also tried "networksetup" commands in the terminal, to no avail.

Comment: I took it to the store and they confirmed it works fine. So it seems to be a software issue.

Comment: You took the adapter to the store? Or both your Macbook Pro and the adapter? How did they test that it works fine?

Comment: They plugged it into another macbook and there it worked. I don't have an Apple store in my city and I have bought my macbook elsewhere, so they are not looking at my macbook for free, which is why I want to solve the issue myself. I am currently downloading Sierra, hoping that an update might fix it, if not I will try to install from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

For strange issues affecting peripherals, your can always try resetting the NVRAM. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help.

Answer (score -1):

I have now solved it by reinstalling mac OS from scratch.